# COSU: Cannot find Activity any more after pin and then restart

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-screen-pinning

I'm developing an App that can be Screen Pinned aka Corporate Owned Single Use aka Lock Task Mode.

If I pin it and then:

- I close it (killing it) and then I launch it again
- or after some code modification in android studio and then perform Run
- **restart after pin and unpin**

I get the following error:

```
[homtom-ht3_pro-0123456789ABCDEF]: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                     Process: com.xx.yyy, PID: 7928
                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.yyy/com.xx.yyy.activities.LauncherActivity}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xx.yyy/com.xx.yy.activities.StartActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                      Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.xx.yyy/com.xx.yyy.activities.StartActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1788)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3809)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3760)
                                                         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4090)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4058)
                                                         at com.xx.yyy.activities.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:16)
                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6099)
                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643) 
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xx.yyy">



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <receiver
            android:name=".receivers.DeviceAdminReceiver"
            android:description="@string/app_name"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin_receiver" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROFILE_PROVISIONING_COMPLETE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".activities.LauncherActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".activities.StartActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

If I don't ever pin the app I can restart/upgrade&run it many times I want.

The nice thing is that is not even possible to uninstall the app because it has been configured as Device Owner, and so, it cannot be uninstalled unless a factory reset.

I dont understand how is possible that my activity disappears after an app restart. Can be something related to the `intent category or action`?

If anyone else encountered this behavior can tell me I will submit an issue to the bug report site.

Thanks.

**EDIT 18/3**

I think maybe this is happening because at a certain point, I kill the `home category activity` that in my case is the missing StartActivity in question, and it is not restarted even if I restart the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution in my COSU disable pinning implementation, I was doing:

```
PackageManager mPackageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();;
mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

to disable the pinning on device boot, but this actually disable the specified component.

The correct implementation would be:

```
PackageManager mPackageManager = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();;
mPackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), StartActivity.class),
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DEFAULT,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```